# Outlook Send Email from Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there any way to specify a folder in outlook that works as an "outbox"? I want to just save emails to this folder, then have outlook pick them up and send them.

Comment: Like a filesystem folder, somewhere on the HDD? or are you talking about an in-outlook folder?

Comment: somewhere on the hard drive.